# ON DELETE CASCADE not working

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

This is the sql for 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    c_id        INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    f_name      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    l_name      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    number      INTEGER,
    date_joined DATE NOT NULL CHECK (date_added <= now())
);

CREATE TABLE Address(
    a_id        INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    c_id        INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Customer(c_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    billing     BOOLEAN,
    f_line      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    s_line      VARCHAR(100),
    county      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    p_code      VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    number      INTEGER(11)
);
```

However when i delete a customer, their address does not get deleted, any ideas why?

Comment: So what happens? It fails? It leaves an orphaned record? What RDBMS?

Comment: I'd guess you use mysql and default engine is MyISAM which doesn't support foreign keys

Comment: Also, script the tables back again to check the foreign key constraint exists and has the cascade delete.

Comment: Im using php/mysql. The customer gets deleted like it shoul, the address asociated with it does not get deleted

Comment: @user195257 -As per a1ex07's comment, are you using MyISAM engine in MySQL?  Also, have you scripte the tables back to double check the foreign key and cascade delete are really there?

Comment: MySQL (even with InnoDB) ignores the inline foreign key definition, so your table is created *without* a foreign key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, cite your source.

Comment: @Charles: That's the "MySQL way" and it's documented in the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html "*Furthermore, InnoDB does not recognize or support 'inline REFERENCES specifications' [...] InnoDB accepts REFERENCES clauses only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you for that.  Turns out we have like ten tables without fkeys thanks to blindly assuming the MySQL wasn't *completely batguano insane*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't really tell for sure without knowing which db you're using, but I think you probably need to declare the fk as a constraint like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Address(
    a_id        INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    c_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    billing     BOOLEAN,
    f_line      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    s_line      VARCHAR(100),
    county      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    p_code      VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    number      INTEGER(11),
     FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES Customer(c_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Good catch. MySQL ignores (without error or warning) the "inline" foreign key definition as shown in the question (even for InnoDB).